# Listener goes into infinite retries when using multirabbit connection

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, multirabbitmq

I'm using [spring-multirabbit](https://github.com/freenowtech/spring-multirabbit) to configure connections to 2 separate rabbitmq servers.

```
spring:
  multirabbitmq:
    enabled: true
    defaultConnection: first-connection
    connections:
      first-connection:
        host: localhost
        port: 5672
        username: guest
        password: guest
      second-connection:
        host: localhost
        port: 5672
        username: guest
        password: guest
```

For local testing, I have them both on localhost, but let's imagine they are 2 remote servers. On the default connection, I'm using only direct exchange with 1:1 communication between queues. On the second connection I have a topic exchange, and a single producer and multiple consumers. On the second connection, if a listener goes into an exception the retry goes on infinitely.

I've tested, and if I remove the multi-rabbit configuration and use the same server for both the direct and topic exchanges, I don't get this infinite retry behavior. It retries 3 times which is configured via properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=1000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=3
```

So obviously, the issue is from the multirabbitmq library. Does someone have experience with it? How do I overwrite/fix the retry behavior on the second connection? Is this a known bug in the library?

I have found this [github issue](https://github.com/freenowtech/spring-multirabbit/issues/73) but had no luck with the proposed solution.

Comment: This is great summary, now where is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's clear enough from the described issue (infinite retries). Updated with a final question: how do I overwrite/fix the retry on the second connection to work the same as the first one?

Answer (score 0):

According to their logic in the current code base, we cannot have a retry configuration per connection factory:

```
   /**
     * Registers the ContainerFactory bean.
     */
    private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory newContainerFactory(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return containerFactory;
    }
```

So, they create a plain `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` based on the specific connection factory, but there is deep diving to the rest of `RabbitProperties` per connection factory.

See some official support for multi-rabbit in Spring AMQP: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#multi-rabbit

Since there is no clean and straightforward auto-configuration for this feature, I suggest you to look into a `setRetryTemplate()` of that `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` you have to configure per connection factory.